# Hide html element when scrolling down to footer

Tags: html, css

I have a bouncing down-arrow and want to hide it when I reach the footer after scrolling down, and show it again when I scroll back to the top. How can I do that without any JavaScript?

```css
.bounce {
  position: fixed;
  left: 95%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #65C178;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -moz-border-radius: 70px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    bottom: 5px;
  }
  25%, 75% {
    bottom: 15px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

Comment: you can't do it without javascript or jquery

Comment: @JishnuVS (jquery actually is a javascript)

Comment: @grilly yes i've accepted , but jquery is  library of a javascript

Answer (score 4):

as far as i know there is no css-only solution. you'll need javascript to determine the scroll position. The only CSSonly way i could think of, is to put the footer in front of the arrow (with z-index). so it gets hidden behind it.